# Python script not downloading all PDFs in the page? (Although it appears as it is downloading them!) It stops after a certain number of them

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup

So, this is the code for downloading all the PDFs in the page:

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Website with translations of hieroglyphs
url = "https://mjn.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/egyptian/texts/corpus/pdf/"

folder_location = "MY FOLDER"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")     
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    name = "".join(x for x in link.string if x.isalnum())
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location, name + ".pdf")
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

The strange thing is that THE SCRIPT GOES ON WITH ALL 325 FILES, and in the console *it prints the message as if it's downloading all the files*, but the folder stops at 95 for some reason. As if it's processing all of them, but stops after 95 (i.e. after the 'books' section of the webpage).

No clue what's happening!

Comment: Have you checked that the filenames it's generating to save the results to are not overlapping? I.e. it's not overwriting a file it wrote previously for some of the later results?

Comment: The length of unique is 94 versus 325 total so overwrites.

Comment: Ooh, so the website actually contains repetitions, right? I thought they were all unique, but apparently it separates them by category and puts them more than once. Thank you, mystery solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what the other commentors said:

```
linklist = []
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    name = "".join(x for x in link.string if x.isalnum())
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location, name + ".pdf")
    linklist.append(filename)
filenames =  list(set(linklist))
```